# Webdriver.io : Wait for method

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a problem in my automatic test scenario when I try to call my function **costumtra** using **webdriver.io.**

I want that the scenario waits until the method call finish

```
describe('senario', function() {
    it('can click submit button', function() {
     //  Do something
        browser.costumtra(browser.element('#submit'));
         //  Do something

    }
});

browser.addCommand("costumtra", function(element) {
 //  Do something
}
```

any solution please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can define custom commands at any point in your test suite, just make sure that the command is defined before you first use it (the before hook in your wdio.conf.js might be a good point to create them). Also to note: custom commands, like all WebdriverIO commmands, can only be called inside a test hook or it block. May be your are calling the test method before define it. change it as given below.

```
browser.addCommand("costumtra", function(element) {
 //  Do something
}
describe('senario', function() {
    it('can click submit button', function() {
     //  Do something
        browser.costumtra(browser.element('#submit'));
         //  Do something

    }
});
```